# Creating a throttle node

Tags: ros, rospy, topic-tools

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I was only able to find documentation online for command line tools for throttling or the other topic_tools for that matter.

Is there a way to create a throttle node from a launch file? I want to go from 30hz to something less. Thanks,

Blair

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/40304/creating-a-throttle-node/) by [bgagnon](https://answers.ros.org/users/2657/bgagnon/) on ROS Answers with karma: 51 on 2012-08-01

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Just use the command line tools in roslaunch:

```
<launch>
  <node name="foo_throttler" type="throttle" pkg="topic_tools" args="messages /input_topic 30 /input_topic_throttled" />
</launch>
```

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-08-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bgagnon](https://answers.ros.org/users/2657/bgagnon/) on 2012-08-01**:
Ha! So simple that I didn't even try that. Thanks!

**Comment by [sedwards](https://answers.ros.org/users/78/sedwards/) on 2012-08-01**:
This is the correct answer but I wish there were a way to inform a node that you don't need the data at the higher rate.  Without this capability, a lot of processing is wasted on the publisher.

**Comment by [ZiyangLI](https://answers.ros.org/users/3542/ziyangli/) on 2015-01-27**:
I have tried this but I can not get the rate I want. For example, my `input_topic` is 200Hz, but my `input_topic_throttled` is only 25Hz, even if I use 100 in the args.

**Comment by [one](https://answers.ros.org/users/45599/one/) on 2020-08-05**:
Ik it's a very late reply to this post but replying if it can help someone else.
for @ZiyangLl comment, you can write it like this:

```
<launch>
<node name = "input_topic_throttler" type="drop" pkg="topic_tools" args= "/input_topic 7 8 /input_topic_throttled" />
</launch>
```

This will drop every 7 frames of incoming 8 frames, So 200/8 = 25 Hz (taking only one frame from every 8 frames, from a 200 frame stack)

**Comment by [distro](https://answers.ros.org/users/75936/distro/) on 2022-04-16**:
@one I guess we replace `input_topic` with the actual topic I wish to  throttle? Also, I would have to make a script where I create the node right?

**Comment by [one](https://answers.ros.org/users/45599/one/) on 2023-01-23**:
Yes, `input_topic` is the topic you want to throttle. I think you can directly add it to your launch file http://wiki.ros.org/topic_tools/throttle